# How can we say that difference in energy between 99.99% and 100% of speed of light is infinite?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

How is it not possible for a particle to attain 100% speed of light and what will happen if it attains the speed of light?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we say that difference in energy between 99.99% and 100% of speed of light is infinite?

The relationship between energy and velocity of an object is not linear but instead follows this equation

$E^2 =  m_0 ^2c^4 + p^2c^2$     (1)

where $p = \gamma m_0 v$

and where $\gamma$

$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2}} $

and as you see, as $v$ approaches $c$, $\gamma$ explodes to an infinite value. So even between 99.99% and 100% there is an infinite range.

You can also use this equation in place of (1)

$E = \gamma mc^2$

> what will happen if it attains the speed of light?

There a quite a few effects like time dilation which ill link below but an interesting one is how mass changes, or more accurately, relativistic mass (how much an object will resist a change in motion). As velocity reaches  near light speed this equation takes affect:

$ m_v = \gamma  m_0 $

where $m_v$ is relativistic mass ans $m_0$ is the mass of the object at rest and $\gamma$ is defined above. As $v$ approaches $c$, $\gamma$ explodes to an infinite value again and the object effectively gains infinite mass, clearly impossible and is a good illustration of why particles with mass can not reach or exceed the speed of light. Massless particles on the other hand can only travel at light speed.

[Here is the wiki link which would describe some other effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity)